# Jquery CKEDITOR many instances how?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

i have a problem with CKEDITOR (the integration) . i don't know:

1 - how to do many instances like :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        CKEDITOR.replace('id1');
        CKEDITOR.replace('id2');
        .
        .
        .
        CKEDITOR.replace('idn');
    });
</script>
```

OR

2 - every textarea in my website be replaced to ckeditor like :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $('textarea').ckeditor();
   });
 </script>
```

thank you :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/58ch1u4o/1/ - looks fine

Comment: yes its ok thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is solved :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('textarea').each(function () {
            CKEDITOR.replace($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });

</script>
```